# How to make a dark credit card more visible

Tags: paint

I have a dark blue credit card, which is hard to see against a black surface in low light. As a result, I and others sometimes cannot see my credit card in restaurants (in the black check booklet) and gas station pumps (in the black card reader).

I want to apply white paint or tape to parts of the credit card for visibility, but I'm worried that it will come off easily, or it will be too thick, resulting in jamming of credit card readers.

Is there a white paint or tape that I could add to my credit card for visibility that would not come off easily, and that would not jam readers?

Comment: Have you tried just asking your bank for another credit card? They may change yours for free.

Comment: I agree with @Ced. I had a card with an illegible number because of the colors. The bank just gave me a new card when I showed it to them and asked for a replacement.

Comment: Hi FlanMan, Welcome to Lifehacks.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy your stay and share your questions and answers with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **NOTHING** at all. Your credit card already comes with a highly-visible and unique "flag."

Fight the STRONG urge to remove it.

When you receive your card, there is a vinyl sticker on the face that says something like, 'STOP. This Card CANNOT be used until…' or 'To activate, make a purchase at any…'

The warning/alert label is quite visible and is meant to be removed after you receive your card and comply with the instruction(s) on it before you use the card.

Just **DON'T** remove the label. It easily lasts as long as the card does and does what you want without doing anything at all. The functionality of your card is not affected in any way.

I have (not) been doing this for years and it has the added benefit of bringing attention to your card by wait-staff, cashiers, tellers, and other relevant personnel who notice the unusual appearance of the card. I like the added attention/care with my credit and debit cards that it seems to provoke on my behalf.

It works.

Comment: I never had a card (neither credit nor debit) with this kind of sticker.

Comment: This, and variations, have worked for me. On an earlier card, I attached a piece of white tape. My current card came with a big white "tap to pay" sticker, which I left in place. After 2 years, I've had no problems.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a neat tab from a piece of **white** (or light grey) **vinyl electrical tape** which is very thin, flexible, has a tenacious hold on the plastic card, and is easier to see.

Fold the vinyl tape back over itself so that it is easy to handle yet has a grip on the top and the bottom of the card. Trim the tape so the "pull tab" looks neat yet won't pick up lint from your pocket or card case.

[image: Credit card with "pull-tab"]

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of "Wite-Out" tape. (Yes, it's really spelled "Wite".) It should apply to your card pretty easily. You can add a spot near each corner to make it easy to see. I have two options to keep it visible over time:

1. Reapplying the Wite-Out tape once a week.
2. Put a piece of clear Scotch tape over the top of each white spot. Then the rubbing will affect the Scotch tape but it will never reach the Wite-out tape.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve marked company and private cards for easy identification. Paint markers come off over time, but have caused no issues. They need reapplying every month or so.

Electrical tape has caused not issues either, and seems to be lasting better. Doesn’t look as neat as freshly applied paint marker.